# Is it possible to create a check constraint in EFCore's Fluent API for MySQL that enforces a field to match a specific regular expression?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I searched and found that Mysql can use check constraints after 8.0.16, but I am not sure if I can use regular expressions to constrain fields, some replies say that this is possible,

in my practice, the keywords LIKE,regexp,regexp_like don't work properly to achieve the corresponding constraints, e.g. regexp_like( `KYCode`,_utf8mb4'[A-Z]%') OR `ColorCode` like _utf8mb4'^[0-9a-zA-Z]$'

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/efcore/EFCore.CheckConstraints/blob/main/README.md

Comment: You are using Entity where the is a mapping between the c# classes and the database.  The constraints are the types declared in the c# classes.  The solution is do the checking in the c# code, not the database.  You should be checking that data when it get stored to the database, not after wrong data is already in the database.

Comment: *`regexp_like( KYCode,_utf8mb4'[A-Z]%')`* Do you use `%` as a pattern "any amount of any symbols"? if so then you are incorrect. *`ColorCode like _utf8mb4'^[0-9a-zA-Z]$'`* Looks like you use regular expression pattern in LIKE which is not correct. *`regexp_like( KYCode, {pattern} ) OR ColorCode like {pattern}`* If any column is NULL then another column can store incorrect value which does not match according pattern. *in my practice, the keywords LIKE,regexp,regexp_like don't work properly* You use them incorrectly, it seems.

Comment: @MarkedasDuplicate you should post this as an answer. I doubt many people know about this package (I didn't). It references the `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` which means it should work with MySQL too

Comment: @jdweng the first comment's link shows someone created a package that does both, unless you use SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Since someone asked me to turn my comment into an answer, there is a package for this: https://github.com/efcore/EFCore.CheckConstraints

> Many databases support something called "check constraints", which allow you to define arbitrary validation for the rows of a table. Think about it like a boring column unique constraint, but on steroids - you can specify that every customer in your table must be either over 18, or have the "parents' permission" bit on. Or whatever makes sense. Just run with it.

Syntax:

```cs
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Range(1, 5)]
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    [MinLength(4)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Required { get; set; }
    [Phone]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [CreditCard]
    public string CreditCard { get; set; }
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Url]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression("^A")]
    public string StartsWithA { get; set; }
}
```